# Endpoints generated client library

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My problem is that I migrated to Endpoints v2, and at some point down the line my GCM registration code stopped working.

Stopped working? More specifically, the generated client library is attempting to send a POST request in the form provided in the top line of this image:

[image: App Engine Log Viewer]

The second line is what happens when I send the request myself manually with Postman (changing it so that it sends the data in the URL fragment instead of in the query string). This works, and is added to my database.

The registration is sent using the standard API builder:

```
Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
    .setRootUrl("https://"+Constants.PROJECT_ID+".appspot.com/_ah/api/");
regService = builder.build();
regService.registerDevice(gcmRegistrationId).execute();
```

The endpoint itself looks like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "registerDevice", httpMethod = "post")
public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId) {
    if(findRecord(regId) != null) {
        log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
        return;
    }
    RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
    record.setRegId(regId);
    ofy().save().entity(record).now();
}
```

How can this be resolved?

My code is being deployed and generated with the following commands:

```
gradlew endpointsOpenApiDocs
gcloud endpoints services deploy backend\build\endpointsOpenApiDocs\openapi.json
gradlew appengineDeploy
gradlew endpointsClientLibs
```

Comment: If you want the parameter to be a query string, it should be marked `@Nullable` as well.

Comment: I don't particularly mind how it is sent. The problem I have is the 404. The system seems to be generating the wrong client library? Or will adding nullable in this case, fix it?

Comment: @saiyr Following your advice, I used `@Nullable`. Worked just fine. My new code is like this: `regService.register().setRegId(regId).execute();`. As you pointed me in the right direction, if you make an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the parameter to be a query string, it should be marked @Nullable as well. This will tell take the parameter out of the path. Looks like there is some mismatch between the configuration in the old and new frameworks, but it is more correct to use @Nullable for query parameters and omit it for path parameters.